# Trigger foundation dropdown only on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a foundation 6 dropdown where it would make sense to trigger it only when it's being "hovered".

```
<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu="nekvg6-dropdown-menu" role="menubar">
   <li class="nav-lorem is-dropdown-submenu-parent is-down-arrow" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Pilates" data-is-click="false">
      <a href="/lorem/?L=0" target="_top" class="active" tabindex="0">Lorem</a>
      <ul class="menu text-left submenu is-dropdown-submenu first-sub vertical" data-submenu="" aria-hidden="true" role="menu">
         <li role="menuitem" class="is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="/lorem/kursdaten/?L=0" target="_top">Kursdaten</a></li>
         <li role="menuitem" class="is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="/lorem/ausbildung/?L=0" target="_top">Ausbildung</a></li>
         <li role="menuitem" class="is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="/lorem/module/?L=0" target="_top">Module</a></li>
         <li role="menuitem" class="is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="/lorem/methode/?L=0" target="_top">Methode</a></li>
         <li role="menuitem" class="is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item"><a href="/lorem/factsheets/?L=0" target="_top">Factsheets</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When the dropdown's trigger (which also has a link in it - which can be clicked ) is **tapped** on a touch device, I'd rather simply follow the link that's inside the triggering element instead of opening the dropdown menu at all.

How should I do that? Using data-whatinput and initializing the menu only when it's on mouse? That sounds a bit quirky.

Is there another, better practice?

Comment: So you what it to open the link `/lorem/?L=0` once it is tapped on mobile device?

Comment: yes, exactly - just follow the link

Answer (score 2):

I could not find any option that does it, Foundation only opens when it is tapped 2nd time.

To do it you have to write a small code to initialize the dropdown menu only if it is **NOT** a touch device.

```
hasTouch = 'ontouchstart' in window || (typeof window.ontouchstart !== 'undefined');
if(!hasTouch){
  var elem = new Foundation.DropdownMenu($('.dropdown.menu'));
}
```

see a working example. http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/yJBJbm

Comment: Nice! Thanks! I'll give feedback as soon as I've tried it

Comment: Thanks again – but I've opted for a different solution in the end so I didn't have to deal with the initialization. There's also "whatinput" data that can be used for touch detection, which is built into foundation https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input

Answer (score 0):

I finally went for a css-only solution, as the dropdown has been initialized via `data-` plugin. Also, if you don't want submenus, you'd have to handle their html.

So I just made two menus toggled them via CSS

```
// Nav with dropdown as default,
// Without dropdown when touch input is detected
#offernav-touch {
    display:none;
}

#offernav-default {
    display:block;
}

[data-whatinput='touch'] {
    #offernav-touch {
        display:block;
    }
    #offernav-default {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

This may seem a bit rough, but in the end it's quite clean.